# Run a test case Multiple times and display the pass and fail count under test statistics

Tags: robotframework

How to run a particular test case multiple times and display the pass and fail count under Test Statistics?

Below is the current code I have to run a test case multiple times. (The test case is implemented in a keyword and called)

```
*** Test Cases ***
Testcase
   repeat keyword    5    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure       Execute

*** Keywords ***
Execute
       log         Hello world!
```

The code is run from cmd using "pybot testcase.robot"

This code runs the test multiple times but I'm not getting the final pass/fail count in the logs. 
I need to manually count the pass and fail test case repetitions.

So what modifications should I do to get the data automatically and should be seen in Test Statistics of the log also.

Comment: could you review your code and make it more clear and explicit? Make a version which is more simple, that shows your "keyword that acts as a test case" and shows how you call it several times. I can not see how your current version works. (use builtin keywords instead of "GetConfigValue" so that we can run your example on our env.

Comment: Changed to a simpler code

Comment: Do you create a report file?

Comment: Robot framework will generate a report.html file once the test execution is completed

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "Repeat Keyword", use For loop.
Use "Run Keyword And Return Status" instead of "Run Keyword And Continue On Failure ".

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Me
    ${fail}=  Set Variable  0
    :FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  5
    \  ${passed}=  Run Keyword and Return Status    Execute
    \  Continue For Loop If  ${passed}
    \  ${fail}=  ${fail} + 1
    ${success}=  Set Variable  5 - ${fail}
    Log Many   Success:  ${success}
    Log Many   fail:  ${fail}
```

Comment: For the record: Native support beyond this will probably not happen: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1856#issuecomment-62808849

Answer (score 0):

You can use a small [pre-run modifier](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-modification-of-test-data) to dynamically replicate the test cases the requested number of times:

```py
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor

class RunMultiple(SuiteVisitor):
    def __init__(self, repeat: int = 2):
        self.repeat = repeat

    def start_suite(self, suite):
        if suite.tests:
            tests = list(t for t in suite.tests)
            suite.tests.clear()
            for tc in tests:
                for n in range(self.repeat):
                    new_tc = suite.tests.create(name=f'{tc.name} Run#{n:03d}')
                    new_tc.tags = tc.tags
                    new_tc.setup = tc.setup
                    new_tc.teardown = tc.teardown
                    new_tc.template = tc.template
                    new_tc.body = tc.body
```

Save this to a file named `RunMultiple.py` (same as the class name) in a folder which is on `PYTHONPATH`, then add this to your robot command line:

```
--prerunmodifier RunMultiple:100
```

to run all test cases 100 times.

(if the prerunmodifier is not on `PYTHONPATH`, specify the full path instead).

Explanation: this prerunmodifier will replace the list of test cases in each suite by as many copies of the original test cases as given as parameter.

RF requires each test case to have a unique name. Therefore, the copies are decorated with a unique suffix. Since all copies share the same tags, you can still do statistics by tag, though.