# Is there any other way to solve this question with the first answer?

Tags: robotframework

[how to execute some test cases multiple times in robotframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419516/how-to-execute-some-test-cases-multiple-times-in-robotframework)

My reputations haven't reached to 50. I could not add the comments. So I'll ask here.
The first answer said that it can do `Robot -t "My test" . . . "My file name"` with the case that you want to run the file multiple times. And '.' represent the times.
I tried it and it did work.
But because some of my cases need to be run by 100 or even 200 times.
Maybe the ways of '.' are not that efficiently.
Is there a way that could use number or more efficiently to represent the times I want to run the files?
Also I want to know what does '.' mean in cmd or robot framework? Where is this method from? Is there a rule of '.'?

Comment: "." refers to current directory - like the reply you referred to said. So, if you define "run tests from current directory" 3 times. you say ". . ."  - robot will scans current directory 3 times and adds the tests matching the tag, 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your operating system scripting tool to create a loop. In a Windows cmd/bat file or in Posix systems a Shell script, using `for`.